# Haskell let in/where and if indentation

Tags: haskell, indentation, let

I have a function:

```
isSimpleNumber :: Int -> Bool
isSimpleNumber x = let deriveList = map (\y -> (x `mod` y)) [1 .. x]
                       filterLength = length ( filter (\z -> z == 0) deriveList
                       ....
```

After filterLength i want to check how much filterLength, i try:

```
isSimpleNumber :: Int -> Bool
isSimpleNumber x = let deriveList = map (\y -> (x `mod` y)) [1 .. x]
                       filterLength = length ( filter (\z -> z == 0) deriveList
                       in if filterLength == 2
                          then true
```

I get error:

```
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How can i put indentation correctly with if and in?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will compile:

```
isSimpleNumber :: Int -> Bool
isSimpleNumber x = let deriveList = map (\y -> (x `mod` y)) [1 .. x]
                       filterLength = length ( filter (\z -> z == 0) deriveList )
                   in filterLength == 2

main = print $ isSimpleNumber 5
```

There was a missing closing ")" after "deriveList". You don't need an if-then-true expression, also.

Answer (score 3):

An `if` needs always both a `then` and an `else` branch, so you probably need `if filterLength == 2 then true else false`, which is equivalent to `filterLength == 2`.